# find common lines in each column within single file

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, perl

I have a file with 2 columns of data. I need to find the lines that have a common string from each column. I'm only interested in the matches line by line, not a matching string from say column 1 line 10 and column 2 line 3.

my file:

```
023q                                              023q023q
0adc                                              0adc0adc
123456                                              123456
abcde                                             abcdefg
08tgdf                                            90alkhg
```

So, in this example, each line except the last line shares a common string, either a portion of the line or the lines are identical, and that's what I need to find. I've seen tons of questions and threads on common strings from 2 files, but nothing so far on my exact use case.

UPDATE: at least 4 characters need to match, in order, on each line.

Comment: At least 4 characters need to match in order. Sorry about that

Comment: I have updated the post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short ***gawk*** approach:

```
awk '(index($1, $2) !=0 && length($2) >= 4) || (index($2, $1) !=0 && length($1) >= 4)' file
```

The output:

```
023q                                              023q023q
0adc                                              0adc0adc
123456                                              123456
abcde                                             abcdefg
```

---

> ***index(in, find)*** 
> Search the string *in* for the first occurrence of the string *find*, and return the position in characters where that
>   occurrence begins in the string *in*.

---

For the more ***complex*** case when we need to find the longest common substring with at least 4 characters length on 2 input strings - I would suggest ***Python*** 
approach:

Let's say the input file was slightly "sophisticated" and had the following lines:

```
1023q                                              023q023q
v0adc                                              20adc0adc
s123456                                              123456
eabcde                                             cabcdefg
08tgdf                                            90alkhg
```

To find the longest common substring we'll use [***SequenceMatcher***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher) class from ***difflib*** module.

`find_common_lines.py` script:

```
import re
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

with open('filename', 'r') as fh:
    for l in fh.read().splitlines():
        items = re.findall(r'\S+', l.strip())  # getting 2 comparable strings
        m = SequenceMatcher(None, items[0], items[1]).find_longest_match(0, len(items[0]), 0, len(items[1]))
        if m.size >= 4:
            print(l)
```

***Usage*** (you may have another *python* 3.x version, the current case has been tested on *python* 3.5):

```
python3.5 find_common_lines.py
```

The output:

```
1023q                                              023q023q
v0adc                                              20adc0adc
s123456                                              123456
eabcde                                             cabcdefg
```

Comment: This works great. Seems to be exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bring the power of `regexes` to bear on this problem at hand and let the `RE` engine do all the heavy lifting while sifting through your data:

```
sed -n '/\(\S\{4,\}\).*\s.*\1/p' yourfile
```

## Results

```
023q                                              023q023q
0adc                                              0adc0adc
123456                                              123456
abcde                                             abcdefg
```